# Why doesn't TypeScript complain when assigning a class to an interface that accepts more params than the class?

Tags: typescript

Why doesn't TypeScript complain when I assign a class to an interface, where the interface is a superset of the class.

Example:

```
interface AI {
  hello(msg: string | number): void;
}

class A {
  hello(msg: string) {}
}

const a = new A();

const b: AI = new A(); // Why not complain here?

a.hello(1); // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
b.hello(1);
```

Comment: Weird, because just the function types [error as expected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwlC8UAUBbAzgcwFxTcATgJYB2GUAPlMQK4oBGE+AlAgHxQBuA9oQCYDcAKADGXYnijCccRKkw48RUi3jtqxXhABmJCAKA)

Comment: This doesn't really have to do with classes, I'm writing up an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TypeScript, methods are always checked [bivariantly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance), meaning that you are allowed to *widen* the types of their parameters, which is safe, or to *narrow* the types of their parameters, which is unsafe, as shown here:

```
interface Iface {
  method(msg: string | number): void; // method syntax
}

const obj: Iface = {
  method(msg: string) { msg.toUpperCase() } // okay?!
}

obj.method(1); // runtime error
```

In this example, `Iface` has a `method()` that needs to accept `string | number`, but `obj`, which is [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) as an `Iface` has a `method()` that only accepts `string`.  The compiler does not warn about this, and you get a runtime error.  This seems like exactly the sort of thing TypeScript is supposed to avoid, but (according to [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance)) it is rare  in practice for people to actually do such unsafe things with bivariant methods. Instead, people tend to do things like this:

```
class Base {
  constructor(public name: string) { }
  compare(other: Base) {
    return this.name.localeCompare(other.name)
  }
}

class Subclass extends Base {
  constructor(name: string, public age: number) { super(name); }
  compare(other: Subclass) {
    return (this.age - other.age) || this.name.localeCompare(other.name)
  }
}
```

It's technically unsafe for `Subclass`'s `compare()` method to accept only a `Subclass` when the `BaseClass`'s `compare()` method accepts any `Base`.  But it's very useful and common to do this sort of thing, and as long as don't upcast a `Subclass` to `Base`, you won't observe the safety hole directly.

---

Anyway, if you're interested in preventing this, you can turn on [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictFunctionTypes) (part of [the `--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict)) and refactor so that any offending method declarations are rewritten as function-valued property declarations:

```
interface Iface {
  method: (msg: string | number) => void; // function-valued prop syntax
}

const obj: Iface = {
  method(msg: string) { msg.toUpperCase() } // error!
  //~~~~ <-- Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
}
```

Now you will get warnings if you unsafely narrow a method parameter in an implementation.  Note that you can still *implement* the method via method syntax; `obj`'s `method` property is not an arrow function and you still get the desired error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-eK6VUmXiJQIAPiQVhs9lpLnp7k8HX8YmQwTLkgr1clfySCkUaUy2Ty52KrUGE14U14zSuFQAfvvd0gADzuz0bHJIADksS0DeAhibl84x2AkKQRw4ilAb2Q6XRm2Qa860US8UnjXsiA6LoaAiWQ+m7RNHCAA)

Comment: I don't agree about it being rare, though I like the rest of the answer. If I am presented with an interface that says I can call a method with string or number, then that's what I'll think is possible. I would have no indication at all that I am doing something unsafe. It seems like a weakness of TypeScript.

Comment: It's straight from the TS documentation linked from the word "bivariantly" above: "In practice, this sort of error is rare, and allowing this enables many common JavaScript patterns" I added "apparently", but I could change it to be more explicit that this is from source material and not my opinion.